# How to clean up mysqli monthly query

Tags: mysqli

I am wondering if there is a better way to perform monthly queries and assign the results into a variable without having to have 12 separate queries? Here is what I have currently.

```
    //Grab JAN
$janquery = "SELECT * FROM $resultsTable WHERE Month( date ) = 1 AND `user_id` = '$userid'";
$jansresult = $link->query($janquery) or die($link->error.__LINE__);
    while($janrow = $jansresult->fetch_assoc()) {
          $janscore = $janrow['score'] + $janscore;
    }
    if($janscore == NULL) $janscore = 0;

    //Grab FEB
$febquery = "SELECT * FROM $resultsTable WHERE Month( date ) = 2 AND `user_id` = '$userid'";
$febsresult = $link->query($febquery) or die($link->error.__LINE__);

    while($febrow = $febsresult->fetch_assoc()) {
          $febscore = $febrow['score'] + $febscore;
    }
    if($febscore == NULL) $febscore = 0;


    //Grab MAR
$marquery = "SELECT * FROM $resultsTable WHERE Month( date ) = 3 AND `user_id` = '$userid'";
$marsresult = $link->query($marquery) or die($link->error.__LINE__);

    while($marrow = $marsresult->fetch_assoc()) {
          $marscore = $marrow['score'] + $marscore;
    }
    if($marscore == NULL) $marscore = 0;
```

**AND SO ON.....**

I am sure there has to be a better way but my brain is not working right now :) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

After a new day and a fresh start I was able to come up with a much easier and a more reasonable solution than running a query 12 times. I will post the answer here incase this may help someone else in the future.

Again, instead of running a query 12 times to get each month's results separately, I can get the same results with just one query.

```
//Grab Each Month's Results
$monthquery = "SELECT * FROM $resultsTable WHERE Year( date ) = '$curYear' AND `user_id` = '$userid'";
$monthresult = $link->query($monthquery) or die($link->error.__LINE__);
    while($monthrow = $monthresult->fetch_assoc()) {
           $datecalories = $monthrow['date'];
           $monthcalories = $monthrow['calories'];

           switch (date("m", strtotime($datecalories)))
           {
                case "1":
                $jancal = $monthcalories + $jancal;
           break;
                case "2":
                $febcal = $monthcalories + $febcal;
           break;
                case "3":
                $marcal = $monthcalories + $marcal;
           break;
                case "4":
                $aprcal = $monthcalories + $aprcal;
           break;
                case "5":
                $maycal = $monthcalories + $maycal;
           break;
                case "6":
                $juncal = $monthcalories + $juncal;
           break;
                case "7":
                $julcal = $monthcalories + $julcal;
           break;
                case "8":
                $augcal = $monthcalories + $augcal;
           break;
                case "9":
                $sepcal = $monthcalories + $sepcal;
           break;
                case "10":
                $octcal = $monthcalories + $octcal;
           break;
                case "11":
                $novcal = $monthcalories + $novcal;
           break;
                case "12":
                $deccal = $monthcalories + $deccal;
           break;
           default:
                $blank = 0;
           }
    }

    if($jancal == NULL) { $jancal = 0; }
    if($febcal == NULL) { $febcal = 0; }
    if($marcal == NULL) { $marcal = 0; }
    if($aprcal == NULL) { $aprcal = 0; }
    if($maycal == NULL) { $maycal = 0; }
    if($juncal == NULL) { $juncal = 0; }
    if($julcal == NULL) { $julcal = 0; }
    if($augcal == NULL) { $augcal = 0; }
    if($sepcal == NULL) { $sepcal = 0; }
    if($octcal == NULL) { $octcal = 0; }
    if($novcal == NULL) { $novcal = 0; }
    if($deccal == NULL) { $deccal = 0; }
```